# Discord js v13 setChannel is undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm started to learn discord.js library and trying to make event when user joins special voice channel and bot creates a new one and moves user. Now bot can create channel, but when it tries to move user it have an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setChannel')"

Here is my code:

```
const {Collection} = require('discord.js')
let privateVoice = new Collection()
config = require('../config.json');

module.exports = async (bot, oldState, newState)=>{
  const user = await bot.users.fetch(newState.id)
  const member = newState.guild.members.fetch(user)
  if(!oldState.channel && newState.channel.id === (config.createChannel)){
    const channel = await newState.guild.channels.create(user.tag,{
      type: "GUILD_VOICE",
      parent: newState.channel.parent
    })
      member.voice.setChannel(channel);
      privateVoice.set(user.id, channel.id)
  }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to fetch a member by their user object and you aren't even `await`ing it. `.fetch` is a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and you use their ID, not their user object.

Instead of using this to get their member object:

```js
const member = newState.guild.members.fetch(user)
```

Use [`VoiceState.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=member)

```js
const { member } = newState //object destructuring for cleaner syntax. 'const member = newState.member' is also fine
```

But this can be `null` since it gets them from the member cache (see [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/VoiceState.js#L132)). If you really want to `fetch` them, make sure to `await` it and use their ID

```js
const member = await newState.guild.members.fetch(user.id)
```